# OCaml: check references are all set

Tags: ocaml

I'd like to write a function that is given a list of option references, and checks that each reference is not `None`. That is, I'd like a function

```
let check rs =
  List.for_all (fun r -> (!r) != None) rs

let _ =
  check [ref (Some 5); ref (Some true)]
```

This doesn't work. The compiler can't find a type for the list `[ref (Some 5); ref (Some true)]`, even though the `check` function seems inherently ok, with its nice polymorphic `'a option ref list -> bool` type.

Is there any way to make this work?

---

My real situation, from which I've distilled the toy example above, is that I'm parsing a number of command-line arguments into a bunch of references. Some of the arguments are strings and some are ints, etc. Initially all of the references are set to `None`, and when the parser finds a command-line argument it sets the corresponding reference to `Some ...`. Having done the parsing, I find myself wanting to iterate over a subset of the references to make sure they're not still `None`, because I want the corresponding command-line arguments to be mandatory.

Comment: `'a option list` means that list element has type `'a option` and all elements should have the same type

Comment: You almost certainly want `<>` instead of `!=`

Comment: @newacct Why's that?

Comment: @JohnWickerson: `=` and `<>` are value equality. `==` and `!=` are physical equality. Physical equality is almost never used, because physical equality is not rigorously documented and varies between types (e.g. `3 == 3` is true, but `3.14 == 3.14` is false), and because you generally never care about whether two things are the same structure in memory or different structures with the same value, unless you are dealing with mutable structures, or doing something really low level with memory.

Comment: @newacct I see, thanks. So in my particular case, since I imagine None == None and None = None both hold, I can use either. But in general I shall try henceforth to remember to use <> instead of !=. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OCaml doesn't support heterogeneous containers. You can try to solve your problem like this:

```
type arg =
  | Unset
  | Int of int
  | Bool of bool
  (* etc *)

let check rs =
  List.for_all (fun r -> (!r) <> Unset) rs

let _ =
  check [ref (Int 5); ref (Bool true); ref Unset]
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to look at your problem is that your list of parameters can't be given a type in OCaml:

```
# [ ref (Some 5); ref (Some true) ];;
Error: This expression has type bool option ref
       but an expression was expected of type int option ref
       Type bool is not compatible with type int
```

If you're willing to wrap your references inside an object interface, you can have the list:

```
# class cr x = object method is_set = !x <> None end;;
class cr : 'a option ref -> object method is_set : bool end
# let reflist = [ new cr (ref (Some 5)); new cr (ref (Some true))];;
val reflist : cr list = [<obj>; <obj>]
```

Then you can check all the elements of the list:

```
# List.for_all (fun x -> x#is_set) reflist;;
- : bool = true
```